# java swing action event after two jbuttons are clicked

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, mouselistener

I am trying to print "Hello" only when the jButton2 is clicked after the jButton1 and print "Bye" only when any other jButtons are clicked after jButton1. At the moment, the following code does not print anything.

```
public void MouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e){
   if (e.getSource() == jButton1) {
        if (e.getSource() == jButton2) {
            System.out.println ("Hello");
        } else {
            System.out.println ("Bye");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For a `JButton`, use an `ActionListener` rather than a `MouseListener` because it will react to keyboard events (e.g. the Enter key to activate) as well as mouse clicks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This code has two problems.

1. Method from parent class is not being overridden. `MouseClicked` should be `mouseClicked` (first letter in small case) as in parent (super) class so that it is overridden and mouse event is captured.
2. There is no point in using nested `if-else` statements as this method would be called on every click and state of any previous clicks on other buttons is not saved.

This code will work for you.

```
boolean button1ClickedLast = false;

public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e){
    if (e.getSource() == jButton1) {
        button1ClickedLast = true;
        System.out.println ("Bye");
    }
    else  if (e.getSource() == jButton2) {
        if(button1ClickedLast) {   
            System.out.println ("Hello");
        }
        else{
            // do nothing or something if you want
        }

    }
    else {
        button1ClickedLast = false; // to change status to false in case any other button is clicked last
    }

}
```

Comment: *"Method from parent class is not being overridden"*  That is where the `@Override` notation in source code comes in handy.  ;)

Answer (score 0):

An event will only come from one button at a time. So in the first buttons eventListener, add code that logs the event in a Boolean variable, then check that variable in the eventListener of the second button to ensure both buttons have been clicked.